# Vue.js - Resetting the filterBy results

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

https://jsfiddle.net/72tnpa0o/

```
<div id="filter-by-example">
  <label>Cool</label><input type="checkbox" v-model="cool">
  <label>notCool</label><input type="checkbox" v-model="notCool">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="user in users | filterBy cool in 'cool' | filterBy notCool in 'notCool'">
      {{ user.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>`



new Vue({
  el: '#filter-by-example',
  data: {
    name: '',
    users: [
      { 
        name: 'Bruce',
        cool: true,
        notCool: false
      },
      { 
        name: 'Chuck',
        cool: false,
                notCool: true
      },
      { 
        name: 'Jackie',
        cool: true,
        notCool: false
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

I have an example up at the fiddle link above. I'm able to sort via the input checkboxes, but unchecking the filters doesn't reset to the original results.

Does anyone know how after unchecking a filter button to get the full array to render?

Comment: Try **ALfredo EM**'s answer. it works perfectly. https://jsfiddle.net/72tnpa0o/4/

Comment: The problem with Alfredo's solution is that it ignores the fact that your code has errors.  `cool` and `notCool` should be defined beforehand in the component. Open the console in the browser and change the checkboxes: you'll see Vue warnings firing like crazy.

Answer (score 1):

**The filter does not apply if the :false-value checkbox is empty**

Try change this:

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="cool">
<input type="checkbox" v-model="notCool">
```

by

```
<input type="checkbox" :false-value="" v-model="cool">
<input type="checkbox" :false-value="" v-model="notCool">
```

Comment: Can you further explain the reason behind this? I have the feeling that, even though it works, it is a hacky solution.

Comment: This solution does work. Thanks Alfredo!

But, like Hector asks, could anyone further explain how this works?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is that the logic of the selector is wrong: as it stands now, if you deselect both checkboxes, you will get the items that are both `cool` and `notCool`. The reason it's working in the beginning is because there's an error in your code (open the console, you will see errors there): both `cool` and `notCool` are `undefined` at the beginning.

So first you need to outline what do you want. Once you've done this, you can use a function to filter instead of using the out-of-the-box one, something like this:

```
<li v-for="user in users | filterBy filterCool">
  {{ user.name }}
</li>
```

And `filterCool` should be like:

```
filterCool: function (element, i, list) {
  if (this.showCool && element.cool) return true;
  if (this.showNotCool && element.notCool) return true;
  if (!this.showNotCool && !this.showCool) return true;
  return false;
}
```

Not a perfect solution right now, but a good way to start. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/72tnpa0o/5/

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to add an key for your list items so that vue can track each item and show relevant data (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key).

Vue 2:

```
<li 
  v-for="(user, key) in users | filterBy filterCool" 
  :key="key"
>
 {{ user.name }}
</li>
```

Vue 1:

```
<li 
  v-for="user in users | filterBy filterCool" 
  track-by="$index"
>
 {{ user.name }}
</li>
```